# What method sets the text of a textbox when a user enters info into a textbox?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, textbox

I am in the process of learning how to implement custom controls by inheriting from parent classes in C#.

I need to override the routine that is fired when the user enters text. Obviously I could add an event to trigger using `TextChanged`, but this seems like dirty cleanup approach to me.

I have looked into override the `Text {get;set;}` property, but this does not work.

Help?

Comment: what doesn't work about overriding the text property and what are you trying to make it do?

Comment: It seems the Text property is only used when attempting to access whats in the textbox via code, (and is not triggered by the end user during run time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) event. Note that users can still paste stuff in without raising a `KeyDown` event. To catch all input, you need to handle `TextChanged` like you thought; there's nothing dirty about it.

Comment: Ah, I am new to custom controls. My normal way of doing would be to change the text after its been entered using `textbox.TextChanged +=`. Which is "dirty" because for a split second the textbox contains incorrect data.

Answer (score 0):

One approach to consider is to create a custom TextBox that extends the standard `TextBox`.  You can `override` a number of properties and methods including `OnKeyPress` to handle user input.

Simple example:

```
class MyTextBox : TextBox
{
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyChar == '!') {
            e.Handled = true;
        } 
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
    }
}
```

The `TextBox` in this example will ignore input when the user enters an exclamation mark.  You would use this TextBox as you would the standard Winform `TextBox` control.

You can use Visual Studio's Intellisense to see what `override`s are available.  Just start to create a new member in the class by typing 'override' and all the overrideable members will appear.

**EDIT**
See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/Simple_Numeric_TextBox.aspx) on codeproject.com for an example.  The control presented in the article extends TextBox to specifically filter out non-numeric characters but you can easily modify it to filter out the characters you need to filter.

Another argument for using a custom control: you can reuse it across projects without having to recode it each time.

Comment: This is my normal approach from my VB6 high school days (if keyascii is unwanted, set keyascii to 0). The e.Handled is new to me. However this doesn't work when the user copies and pastes, and `OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)` event args do not have a `.Handled` property

Comment: @James I did say mine was a simple example.  I found an article over at codeproject.com that uses the same technique of extending the TextBox to do what you need to do, including handling C&P.